# $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be identified with $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

The following snippet is from the "Dimensions" chapter of "Linear Algebra Done Right", by Sheldon Axler. I have the following questions:

1. What does "identified with" mean in this context?
2. What does this have to do with the "role played by the choice of F"?

[image: textbook snippet]

Comment: They mean the bijection $a+bi \rightarrow (a,b)$.

Comment: "Identified with" means that they're basically the same thing; there's a bijection between them. The point $(x,y)$ in the real plane is like $x+iy$ in the complex plane.

Comment: I assume it's referring to elements of both $R^2$ and $C$ being described by a *pair* of numbers, two reals for elements in $R^2$, a real part and imaginary part for elements in $C$ (i.e. the graph of $R^2$ is a plane, as is the graph of $C$ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any complex number can be written uniquely in the form $a+ib$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. This could also be written as the ordered pair $(a,b)$ with rules for multiplying ordered pairs together - $(a,b)\times (c,d)=(ab-cd,ad+bc)$. If we forget about the multiplication in $\mathbb C$ we can regard it therefore as a set of ordered pairs of real numbers $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2$ - the points of a two dimensional real plane. In fact $\mathbb C$ is (can be regarded as) a vector space of dimension two over the real numbers.

So the plane can be regarded as two dimensional over $\mathbb R$, but it is only one-dimensional over $\mathbb C$ - each point in the plane is identified with a unique element of $\mathbb C$.

So depending on which field we take for the ground field, the dimension of the plane changes.

In fact whenever we have one field included in another, the larger field can be regarded as a vector space over the smaller one (it has more structure than that, but the vector space structure is still there). So the larger field has dimension $1$ over itself, but some other dimension over the smaller field. In some parts of mathematics (eg Galois Theory) this happens a lot. It seems strange at first, but it is worth getting used to.